# What code can I use to make my button fall to the left

Tags: css, button, design-patterns

I'm designing an app and I can't seem to think of a CSS ruleset to make a button fall to the left. [image: This is an image of what I have]

So I'm basically trying to make the reset button fall to the left of the number, that is, to the point circled below.[image: This is the point I want the reset button to be]I need a CSS ruleset to achieve this.

This is the general CSS code for all the buttons.

```
button {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #42b983;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

NB: Float won't help in this case

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.counting {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

button {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* 
.resetContainer{
        display: flex;
        /* flex-direction: row; */


/* } */


/* .reset{
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    } */

button:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="counting">
    <h1 class>Counter</h1>
    <button>Increment</button>
    <!-- <div class="resetContainer"> -->
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
    <!-- </div> -->
    <p>0</p>
    <button>Decrement</button>
    <button>Set Value</button>

  </div>
```

Comment: Please post relative html and css into a [mcve]

Comment: I've edited the question to include one

Comment: How do you want to align the elements?

Comment: I want the Reset button to be to the left of the number in the middle, and the Set Value button to be to the right of the same number so it has a kind of cross-like look

Answer (score 0):

You can place reset button at left using this way

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title> CSS </title>
    <head>
    <style>
    
    #resetcontainer{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    #reset{
            margin-right: 30px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="resetcontainer">
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        <p>0</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the add post guideline properly before posting. If you added your code with the post it would be more easy to solve this problem. I don't know how you wrote the code but here I'm trying to give you a solution.

Create a parent div and put the button inside if it.

```html
<div class="reset-parent">
    <button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.reset-parent {
    display: flex;
}

.reset-parent .reset-btn {
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Again, I'm not sure how you wrote the code so it is not possible to give you an exact solution. But you can follow this way, hopefully it'll help you.

Comment: I've updated it to include the code and an MRE, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want the reset button and the number in same row, use the code here. I put the button and number inside a div so that it'll be in the same row.

```
<div class="counting">
    <h1 class>Counter</h1>
    <button>Increment</button>
    <div class="reset-number">
        <button class="reset">Reset</button>
        <p>0</p>
    </div>
    <button>Decrement</button>
    <button>Set Value</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
}
p{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.counting {
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
button {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #42b983;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.reset-number{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 50px;
}
```